# Two ListView in same activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I want to build one activity with two listviews. One that scroll horizontally. One that scroll vertically. The two adapter attached are customized with image and text and load their data from two different sqlite tables.

i've googled for two/three months without result... there's no example that answer to my question

How can i do?

Sorry for my poor english
Gianni Maiorani

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK does not provide a horizontally scrolling ListView. You can use an open source [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34).

See the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) for populating your ListViews with child views that contain image/text.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example for horizontal list view 
http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 
as for the vertical listview i think there will be no problem in it